# Express Router with Decision

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Routing With Middleware checks based req.query**
how to choose the next() based on req.query property

Example:

```
const preQueryCheck = (req,res,next)=>{
  //??
}

Router.route(‘/add/:id’).post(preQuerycheck,addsum)
```

*What I want is if req.query = type:sum
I want it to go to addsum
If it’s subtract it shd go to subtract !!
Is it possible ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example of writing your own middleware:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED')
  next()
}

app.use(myLogger)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

So in this case the middleware function is myLogger!

Comment: what i actually need is based on query property i want it to choose the controller!!

Comment: Yeah so you have to write a middleware that returns the name of the controller from the prequery function.